# Creating a number guessing game where the computer guesses the number, list slicing

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to create a program where the computer guesses a number from an ordered list, and if it is too high, then the list is sliced to only include lower numbers, and if it is too low the list is sliced to only include higher numbers.  Then the computer guesses again.

For some reason, the list doesn't slice correctly.  I don't really see a pattern, but here is an example:

(I'm thinking of 46)

guess: 4 
too low 
new list: [5:99] 
guess: 92 
too high 
new list: [5:96] (it should have been [5:91]) 
guess: 63 
too high 
new list: [5:67] (should be [5:63]) 
guess: 58 
too high 
new list: [5:62] (should be [5:58]) 
...

Here is my code:

```
import random

guess_list = [x for x in range(1, 100)]
guess = random.choice(guess_list)

def computer_guessing_game(guess, guess_list):
  print(guess)
  response = input("is this correct, too high, or too low?: ")

  if response == "correct":
    print('smart computer')
  
  elif response == "too low":
    print("too low, try again")
    guess_list = [x for x in guess_list[guess:]]
    guess = random.choice(guess_list)
    print(guess_list)
    computer_guessing_game(guess, guess_list)
  
  elif response == "too high":
    print("too high, try again")
    guess_list = [x for x in guess_list[:guess]]
    guess = random.choice(guess_list)
    print(guess_list)
    computer_guessing_game(guess, guess_list)
  
computer_guessing_game(guess, guess_list)
```

Comment: You're right, I should not have said binary search.... the computer is randomly guessing numbers within the list

Comment: You're confusing indexes with the value at that index.

Comment: The pattern is 4+92=96. 63+4=67. 58+4=62. It's because your array starts at a different point after you slice the list

Comment: It would be more efficient to store a min and a max rather than the whole list of numbers

Comment: @ThomasWeller why would it matter if it started at a different point, if I am just using [:guess] (no start point) and [guess:] (no end point)?

Comment: @SimonCrane that actually makes a lot more sense, thanks for the tip

Comment: `[:guess]` with guess=5 will give you everything until **index** 5 (exclusive), not until the **value** 5. If your array is `[4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, the result will be `[4,5,6,7,8]`, not `[4,5]`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying.... that explains the pattern.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion, I got rid of the list and instead used minimum and maximum numbers:

```
guessing = random.randint(1, 100)
minimum = 1
maximum = 100
count = 1
def guessing_game_two(guessing, minimum, maximum, count):
  print(guessing)
  response = input("is this correct, too high, or too low?: ")

  if response == "correct":
    print('smart computer, and it only took you {} tries'.format(count))

  elif response == "too low":
    count += 1
    minimum = guessing + 1
    guessing = random.randint(minimum, maximum)
    guessing_game_two(guessing, minimum, maximum, count)

  elif response == "too high":
    count += 1
    maximum = guessing - 1
    guessing = random.randint(minimum, maximum)
    guessing_game_two(guessing, minimum, maximum, count)

guessing_game_two(guessing, minimum, maximum, count)
```